# Chef metadata.rb dependency needs to depend on itself

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am getting a foodcritic error when I try to include a recipie within the default.rb for the apache cookbook lesson:

```
#
# Cookbook:: apache
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2017, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.
# Install apached package
package 'apache2' do
    package_name 'httpd'
    action :install
end
service 'apache2' do
    service_name 'httpd'
    action [:start, :enable]
end

include_recipe 'apache::websites'
```

websites.rb

```
file 'default www' do
path '/var/ww/html/index.html'
content 'Hello world!'
end
```

When I run foodcritic on default.rb

```
FC007: Ensure recipe dependencies are reflected in cookbook metadata: 
default.rb:17
```

When I follow the recomendation and add the dependency in the metadata.rb and run **knife cookbook upload apache** I get this:

```
ERROR: RuntimeError: Cookbook depends on itself in cookbook apache, please 
remove the this unnecessary self-dependency
```

Below is my metadeta.rb

```
name 'apache'
maintainer 'xxxxx'
maintainer_email 'xxxxx'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures apache'
long_description 'Installs/Configures apache'
version '0.1.1'
chef_version '>= 12.1' if respond_to?(:chef_version)
depends 'apache'

#The `issues_url` points to the location where issues for this cookbook are
# tracked.  A `View Issues` link will be displayed on this cookbook's page 
when
# uploaded to a Supermarket.
#
# issues_url 'https://github.com/<insert_org_here>/apache/issues'

# The `source_url` points to the development repository for this cookbook.  
A
# `View Source` link will be displayed on this cookbook's page when uploaded 
to
# a Supermarket.
#
# source_url 'https://github.com/<insert_org_here>/apache'
```

New to chef and ruby, first question on Stack Overflow.
Am I adding the dependency wrong?
Does anything jump out that would cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FC007 activation is wrong. Are you sure you're running `foodcritic` correctly? Just run `foodcritic .` on the base of the cookbook folder (i.e. the same place as the `metadata.rb` is). That should detect the name of the cookbook and not flag the include.

Comment: You're right. I removed the depends 'apache' line from the metadata.rb file and ran foodcritic . as you suggested. Now I have other issues, but I will need to post another question about it.